# MongoDB - Query base on field type array

Tags: arrays, mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query, pymongo

I am having a problem with array query in mongoDB
I have collection with documents format like so:

```
{
    'data':
    [
        { 'itv': [0, 1], 'name': 'a' },
        { 'itv': [6, 8], 'name': 'b' },
        ...
    ]
}
```

I want to query documents that **data** have at least one element that matches the condition **itv[1]-itv[0] > n**

Comment: You can try an aggregation query with a `$filter` array operator to filter the `data` array field.

Comment: Can i using  `$elemMatch` in `data`  with condition  `itv[1]-itv[0] > n`  ?. I can wirte this query, can u help me , thank you

Comment: You can't use `$elemMatch` with that no.

Answer (score 0):

You can calculate this either in the aggregation pipeline or using `$expr` with the query language, like so:

```
const n = 1;
db.collection.find({
  $expr: {
    $gt: [
      {
        $size: {
          $filter: {
            input: "$data",
            cond: {
              $gt: [
                {
                  $subtract: [
                    {
                      "$arrayElemAt": [
                        "$$this.itv",
                        1
                      ]
                    },
                    {
                      "$arrayElemAt": [
                        "$$this.itv",
                        0
                      ]
                    }
                  ]
                },
                n
              ]
            }
          }
        }
      },
      0
    ]
  }
})
```

[Mongo Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/e2Zw4clqniP)

My personal recommendation will be to pre-calculate the difference, this means the new schema will look a little something like:

```
{
    'data':
    [
        { 'itv': [0, 1], 'diff': 1, 'name': 'a' },
        { 'itv': [6, 8], 'diff': 2, 'name': 'b' },
        ...
    ]
}
```

Now you can query this with a simple find query:

```
const n = 1
db.collection.find({ 'data.diff': { '$gt': n }})
```

To retroactively update your collection you can use this update:

```
db.collection.updateMany({},
[
  {
    $set: {
      data: {
        $map: {
          input: "$data",
          in: {
            $mergeObjects: [
              "$$this",
              {
                diff: {
                  $subtract: [
                    {
                      $arrayElemAt: [
                        "$$this.itv",
                        1
                      ]
                    },
                    {
                      $arrayElemAt: [
                        "$$this.itv",
                        0
                      ]
                    }
                  ]
                }
              }
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
])
```

[Update Mongo Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/L9isikcptAP)

Comment: I'm not familiar with query optimization. But in my case `data` have about 2000 elements while i need only one element in `data` that matching with condition `itv[1]-itv[0] > n`. I dont now when i using `$filter` maybe all 200 elements will be caculate `itv[1]-itv[0] > n` ?  or when one element matched=> it will be break ?

Comment: From a query perspective there's not much you can do as you have to iterate, my recommendation is to preprocess this value when you insert the document so it's a simple query, i'll add this to my answer